# How to see managed stack in htrace in windbg?

Tags: windbg, handle

After enabling htrace for managed application and running !htrace on a handle displays native stack. But managed stack is not visible. How to make !htrace to display managed and native stack?

```
0:038> !htrace 0x000000000000160c
--------------------------------------
Handle = 0x000000000000160c - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x0000000000005e18, Process ID = 0x00000000000030c8

0x000000007797bfba: ntdll!NtCreateEvent+0x000000000000000a
0x000007fefd6a2d15: KERNELBASE!CreateEventExW+0x0000000000000061
0x000007fef768320b: clr!CLREventBase::CreateManualEvent+0x0000000000000028
0x000007fef776f6f1: clr!Thread::AllocHandles+0x0000000000000051
0x000007fef776fa05: clr!Thread::CreateNewOSThread+0x0000000000000091
0x000007fef776f92e: clr!Thread::CreateNewThread+0x00000000000000ae
0x000007fef77701a9: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateUnimpersonatedThread+0x00000000000000c5
0x000007fef77702f0: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateWorkerThread+0x0000000000000019
0x000007fef7799507: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::MaybeAddWorkingWorker+0x0000000000000113
0x000007fef77709cc: clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x0000000000000024
0x000007fef7770a6a: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x000000000000002a
0x000007fef7770a06: clr!ThreadPoolNative::RequestWorkerThread+0x000000000000002b
0x000007fef644cfaa: mscorlib_ni+0x000000000057cfaa
0x000007fef637725e: mscorlib_ni+0x00000000004a725e
```

Comment: IMHO there's no built-in command to do that. You'd probably need to resolve suspicious addresses yourself.

Comment: One thing you could try is to take the address in each stack frame and pass it to `!sosex.mln`. It's not automatic, but it's better than nothing.